# LookupError: App 'Hierarchy' doesn't have a 'CustomUser' model

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-custom-user

I've been following the Django documentation to create a custom user model.

Here is the main error - 
(Edit - I was asked to add the entire traceback so here it is)

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 178, in get_model
    return self.models[model_name.lower()]
KeyError: 'customuser'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 156, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 210, in get_model
    return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 181, in get_model
    "App '%s' doesn't have a '%s' model." % (self.label, model_name))
LookupError: App 'Hierarchy' doesn't have a 'CustomUser' model.
```

To make matters worse after that is shows the below error, I've done everything that the site told me to, couldn't find the answer anywhere

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute 
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models        
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Coding\TimeSheet\_OFFICIAL_\InsemiTimeSheet\Project\Infrastructure\InsemiSystem\Hierarchy\models.py", line 3, in <module>       
    from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 6, in <module>        
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 20, in <module>       
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 161, in get_user_model
    "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'Hierarchy.CustomUser' that has not been installed
```

I have defined it in my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager)
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
     #I proceeded to create the User details here
```

I also added it correctly as the AUTH_USER_MODEL using -

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Hierarchy.CustomUser'
```

Comment: Could you please post all traceback?

Comment: @ncopiy added the full traceback, hope it can help identify the error

Comment: have you added 'Hierarchy' to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py ? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#installed-apps

Comment: @ncopiy yes, that was the first thing we checked and it was there. This error shouldn't be coming honestly can't understand why it's happening.

Comment: try to replace `Hierarchy` by `Hierarchy.apps.HierarchyConfig` (check out you have an apps.py with `HierarchyConfig` cls)

Comment: @ncopiy Nope, tried that too, did not work.

Comment: did you run migrations before? may be it really not registered model because there is no info about it migrations

Comment: @ncopiy I did that. I've tried all the basic solutions and searched everywhere on the depths Stack Overflow before asking here.

Comment: @ncopiy The error itself arises when I try to migrate which is the main issue. Makemigrations and runserver seem to have the same issue.